# Differentiate queues in process builder for email notification

Tags: process-builder, queue, public-group

I have a process builder workflow setup that sends out new task email notifications.  I would like to differentiate the the email notifications based on the queue that it is getting sent to.

A simplified example is that we have one queue that is for the US Sales and another queue that is for international sales.  I would like one style email template to be sent for the US and another for international.  I don't want to go off of the queue name since I would need to maintain that and this list will grow over time.

I originally was looking into custom metadata types, but not sure if that will work.  Any advise is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need a mapping of the queue and email template.
The "Email Alerts" action in process builder does not support any criteria for sending email. So you would have to differentiate the queue by using multiple decision nodes or one 'catch-all' node and invoke an apex to send the email (by reading the mapping from custom metadata types).

Or if your email templates are only slightly different between them, you might want to consider using `CASE()` formula in the template.